# runtimeexception:unable to destroy activity and RuntimeException:.nosuchfieldexception: mChildfragmentManager

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I'm really having a hard time figuring this out. When I looked where the logcat points the error, it points to this line:

```
throw new RuntimeException(i);
```

inside this

```
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException i) {
        throw new RuntimeException(i);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException i) {
        throw new RuntimeException(i);
    }
}
```

This happens when I changed to landscape orientation. I know the view is being recreated after a change of orientation, I was able to do this on my Google maps also in this app, but I don't know how to implement it on a webview. I have a webview that shows facebook sharer.php and when I change it to landscape orientation, it force stops.

This is my code for this tab:

```
public class TabFour extends Fragment {

static WebView webView;
String myBlogAddr = "http://192.168.1.75/Treasuria-v2/";
String myUrl;
Button map;
View rootView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_four, container, false);

    displayWebview();
    return rootView;


}

protected void displayWebview(){
webView= (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);


    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    String title = "Quezon City Guide";
    String desc = "Your Number One City Guide!";
    String image = "http://s22.postimg.org/5t4qidqpt/launcher114x114.png";

    myBlogAddr ="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?m2w&s=100&p[title]="+title+"&p[summary]="+desc+"&p[url]=http://www.sample.com&p[images][0]="+image;
    if(myUrl == null){
        myUrl = myBlogAddr;
    }
    webView.loadUrl(myUrl);
    Log.i("URL", myBlogAddr);

    map = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);

    map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
        }
    });
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        myUrl = url;
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}


public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack())
        webView.goBack();
}

public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
    map = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMap);

    map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException i) {
        throw new RuntimeException(i);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException i) {
        throw new RuntimeException(i);
    }
}

}
```

**GoogleMap Tab**

```
public class TabTwo extends Fragment {

private static View view;

private static GoogleMap map;
private static Double latitude, longitude;
private static LatLngBounds QC = new LatLngBounds(
      new LatLng(14.656669, 120.998598), new LatLng(14.666965, 121.098934));

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_two, null);
    // Passing hard coded values for latitude & longitude. Please change as per your need. This is just used to drop a Marker on the Map
            latitude = 14.6353475;
            longitude = 121.0327501;
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            setUpMapIfNeeded(); // For setting up the MapFragment

    return view;
}

/***** Sets up the map if it is possible to do so *****/
public static void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (map == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the
 * camera.
 * <p>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap}
 * is not null.
 */
private static void setUpMap() {
    // For showing a move to my location button
     map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Estuar Building").snippet("Work Place"));
    // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
            longitude), 12.0f));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (map != null)
        setUpMap();

    if (map == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) MainActivity.fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null)
            setUpMap();
    }
}

/**** The mapfragment's id must be removed from the FragmentManager
 **** or else if the same it is passed on the next time then 
 **** application will crash ****/
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    try {
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
        setUpMap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException i) {
        throw new RuntimeException(i);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException i) {
        throw new RuntimeException(i);
    }
}
 }
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: is mChildFragmentManager variable exists in Fragment class?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. I also used this method in my map tab to handle orientation changes

Comment: means, you are trying to access a field variable named mChildFragmentManager which is not available in Fragment class

Comment: ok i get that. But that didn't happen on my Google Map Class. Why is it that?

Comment: although my TabFour is a fragment, there is no fragment on the layout, just a webview for accessing facebook share.

Comment: sorry, really I don't know about Google Map class? where it is?

Comment: wait i'll edit my post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39880/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-miguel-rivera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
public void onDetach() {
super.onDetach();
try {
  Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
  childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
  childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException i) {
  } 
 catch (IllegalAccessException i) {
 }
```

}

Comment: This bug is being tracked in the Android Open Source issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601